# How to pass arguments to functions in another file? - React 17.0.1

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I have this file Foo.js:

```
const Foo= ({ someArg }) => {
  alert(someArg);
};

export default Foo;
```

I am calling it from App.js:

```
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    Foo("text");
  }, []);
...
```

The function gets called, but the alert shows `undefined` instead of the actual value that was passed. How do I properly pass arguments to a function in another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are destructuring a string which doesn't have a property called `someArg`. That's why `undefined` is displayed.

##### Correct Way:

```
const Foo= (someArg) => { // No destructuring
  alert(someArg);
};

export default Foo;

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    Foo("text"); // You are passing a string
}, []);
```

```
const Foo= ({ someArg }) => { // Doing destructuring
  alert(someArg);
};

export default Foo;

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    Foo({someArg: "text"}); // You are passing an object
}, []);
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment